# Make a status change column based on current row and the next row of a column

Tags: sql

I have the following data

```
ID       Period     Status    
 1        One          0    
 1        Two          1   
 2        One          0    
 2        Two          1   
 3        One          1    
 3        Two          0      
 4        One          1    
 4        Two          0   
 5        One          1    
 5        Two          1    
 6        One          0    
 6        Two          0
```

Each id has the status of the two ordinal periods (One and Two). I wish to get the status change group by id.
The desired results would look like this:

```
ID     Change Status           
 1            1    
 2            1  
 3            2    
 4            2     
 5            3   
 6            4
```

- Change Status 1 means status increases from 0 to 1.
- Change Status 2 means status decreases from 1 to 0.
- Change Status 3 means status stays the same from 1 to 1.
- Change Status 4 means status stays the same from 0 to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of getting the desired result. Assuming that there will be always two rows for each id in the original table.

```
WITH PatritionTable (RecordNumber,Id,Period,Status) AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ID) AS RecordNumber, 
            Id,
            Period,
            Status
        FROM Table1)

SELECT A.ID,
   CASE WHEN A.Status = 0 AND B.Status = 1 THEN 1
       WHEN A.Status=1 AND B.Status=0 THEN 2
       WHEN A.Status = 1 AND B.Status = 1 THEN 3
       WHEN A.Status = 0 AND B.Status=0 THEN 4
   END AS Status

FROM PatritionTable A
JOIN PatritionTable B
     ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.RecordNumber = 1 AND B.RecordNumber=2
```

Based on your comment, this is the second version. Here number of rows for each id is not hard coded. The thing here is that, it only takes the first and last row for the id, ignoring the in between rows, by using the criteria `B.Period = B.LastRecord`.

```
WITH PatritionTable (RowNumber, LastPeriod, Id,Period,Status) AS (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ID) RowNumber,
            LAST_VALUE (Period) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ID) LastPeriod,
            Id,
            Period,
            Status
        FROM Table1)

SELECT A.ID,
CASE WHEN A.Status = 0 AND B.Status = 1 THEN 1
     WHEN A.Status=1 AND B.Status=0 THEN 2
     WHEN A.Status = 1 AND B.Status = 1 THEN 3
     WHEN A.Status = 0 AND B.Status=0 THEN 4
END AS Status
FROM PatritionTable A
JOIN PatritionTable B
ON A.Id = B.Id 
    AND B.Period = B.LastPeriod
    AND A.RowNumber= 1
```

Comment: Thank you ! This works for two time periods. What if there are three rows for each id? or four.

Comment: Would that be using CASE WHEN compare A and B, and then B and C?

Comment: I dont think so it will hold if more than 2 records are there for single ID.

Comment: @Iwishworldpeace, added the version for any number of rows

Answer (score 2):

Using the LAG function to get the previous value:

```
select x.*, case when "Status" = 1 and prev_value = 0 then 1 
            when "Status" = 0 and prev_value = 1 then 2
            when "Status" = 1 and prev_value = 1 then 3
            else 4 end as Change_status from (
SELECT A.*, LAG("Status") OVER(PARTITION BY id order by "Period") prev_value
from table1 a) x where prev_value is not null order by id;
```

Comment: @Iwishworldpeace . . . This looks like the better approach to me (although the query could definitely be formatted more clearly).

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff I will take care going forward.